# Remove string from column whitout getting an NAN

Tags: pandas, replace, nan

I have a DataFrame like:

```py
DF = {'Col':  [1, 2, 3,...,100, 10-1 , 10-2]}
```

I'd like to get rid of the "-" on last two rows. If I use replace on column, I get NaN for the values that don't have a "-".

e.g.

```
DF['Col'] = DF['Col'].str.replace('-','')
```

results in:

```
DF = {'Col':  [NAN, NAN, NAN,...,NAN, 101 , 102]}
```

Is there a way to delete the "-" without getting NaN on other rows?

Comment: store it in another column, then use apply like `lambda x: x.replacement if x.value == '-' else x.value`

Comment: `DF['Col'].str.replace('-','').fillna(DF['Col'])`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because there is a mix of integer value and strings. First convert the whole columns to string:

```
>>> df['Col'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '')
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    100
4    101
5    102
Name: Col, dtype: object

# Without cast
>>> df['Col'].str.replace('-', '')
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    101
5    102
Name: Col, dtype: object
```

Obviously, now you can revert it and convert your column to int:

```
>>> df['Col'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '').astype(int)
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    100
4    101
5    102
Name: Col, dtype: int64
```